# How can I update the list of answers to an upcoming question in Google Forms based off of previous answers in the same form?

Tags: google-forms

The title makes this sound more difficult or complex than it actually is.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to build an entire elimination bracket prediction picker through Google Forms. I would have 16 predetermined teams in an elimination style tournament where I split them into their 8 1v1 predetermined match-ups. From here I want to have the user predict the next round which would have half the matches of the previous round but I can't find a way to have all the teams that the user predicted to be eliminated in the first round to be removed as options in the second round. So if someone picked Team 1 to beat Team 2 in the first round I don't want Team 2 to be an option to win in the next round. This makes it so when the user gets to the final they don't have to select the winner out of 16 teams, but rather just 2 since half the teams are eliminated each round. This would also allow this form to scale to much bigger tournaments like for Tennis where there can be many more rounds and competitors.

The only things I could find that are similar are choice eliminator add-ons that remove choices from all forms. Unfortunately that's only appropriate for scheduling appointments and won't work for this use case since I want people to have all permutations of the bracket available when they predict.